# Parsing of multi-line error message with LaTeX suite in vim

Tags: vim, latex-suite

I'm using [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) with [latex-suite](/questions/tagged/latex-suite). Compilation is done with `<leader>ll`, I see the quickfix window but multi-line error messages don't get parsed correctly. For example, a one-line error message is parsed correctly:

```
analysis.tex|26 warning| Overfull \hbox (10.50328pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 26--27
```

If I press <kbd>enter</kbd> while the cursor is on this line, the cursor jumps to the correct line in the correct file. For a multi-line error message I only get the first line:

```
analysis.tex|189 warning| LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:feynman-sm-stus' on page 6 undefined on input lin
```

I do not just see only one line of a multi-line error message, the line number is also wrongly parsed (it should be 160, not 189).

These errors should be pretty common, so I wonder if anyone has a fix for it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an issue tracker; please submit your problem to the latex-suite project to get help or a fix.